# .NET Mvc 3 to return OData JSON result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, odata

I am trying to get ASP.NET MVC3 to return an array as an OData result.

I am not planning and do not want to use WebAPI in MVC4, because it removes the abstractions that we already have in place. Namely, we do not expose our underlying table schema/structure to the application layer - ever.

So I intend to manually parse the OData query myself, which is not a big deal.

However, how should I return the result set in a manner consistent with the OData (JSON) formats. I'm looking to find out if some prior work exists.